# On-premises to PaaS while not using MVC (WebForms implementation)

Tags: azure, webforms, cloud

We have a project which is running on Sitecore 9.0.2 however this was build using traditional form rendering rather than MVC rendering. We would like to move this project on cloud - Sitecore PaaS.

What is the possibility to move this kind of project to PaaS?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To answer your question, PaaS is simply another way of saying that an IIS site exists that allows you to run a website.  Said differently, using the Sitecore Azure Toolkit to deploy a vanilla instance of Sitecore 9.0.2 to Azure PaaS and then deploying your code base through a WebDeploy package should be sufficient to utilize PaaS.

Things to consider when moving to PaaS:

1. Are you using Solr or Azure Search?
2. How will you migrate your content? I would advocate that if you are using Unicorn/TDS, let it deploy out the item structure first, and then package up any content from the On Prem site and install on the PaaS Sitecore.
3. Ensure that your configuration transforms are correctly done taking into account the domain name changes for most of xConnect.
4. If you aren't already, consider using Azure DevOps for Deployment (formerly VSTS).
5. Ensure that Session State is not InProc and that you are using Azure Redis Cache for Sessioning.

I think a larger conversation is questioning the intention around using WebForms and not MVC, but I don't want to detract from the question at hand.

Comment: Thanks Pete and Dan. The project size is very huge and do not have quick plan to  move on MVC however would like to utilize PaSS env. Your answer helps me to move ahead. Thanks.